# Jquery load html on a div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to load a html page on a div class on my page, but my html page have just a script src ... but is not loading the page on div class ...

This is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() { // this runs as soon as the page is ready (DOM is loaded)
  $(".Ads_Banner").load("/home/funny/public_html/template/ads_template.php");
 });
```

This is in my html page ( what im trying to load ) :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://adspaces.ero-advertising.com/adspace/113423.js"></script>
```

If in the html i put just "Text" is working but when i try to load the script is show me blank ... hope someone can tell me how i can make this so ads to be loaded after the website is done loading ...

Comment: The ad script you are trying to load will not work with ajax because it is using document.write(), which will completely overwrite your page if used after the document is ready (which will almost always be the case due to requesting said script asynchronously). Look to your ad provider for an alternative, or don't use AJAX to retrieve it.

Comment: what i need is to load the html on the div class to be something like <div class="Ads_Banner"><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://adspaces.ero-advertising.com/adspace/113423.js"></script></div> ... i dont need the ajax to load the script from the ads website, i just need to put that code on div class ...

Comment: Then put it in the div manually, without using javascript. That's your only option other than finding an alternative from the ad provider. I guess you could also use an iFrame, however be very careful with that because it is against the TOS of some ad providers due to the invalid impressions it may generate, which could lead to losing your membership with said ad provider.

Comment: i have problems with this ads sometimes they stay to long loading ... and my js scripts is loading after the website finish loading ... any way to make the ads to be loaded after the website is done loading ?

Comment: Due to the way the ad script was written, no. It has to be executed while the DOM is being built, before the closing tag of the div is parsed. I'd suggest contacting the ad provider and explaining the problem you are having, they may have an alternative.